# ScrollView Content not filling when stack view is embedded in it

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard, uistackview

I have embedded stack view inside scrollView and added top bottom left and right constraints. Also I have fixed height of scrollView. The StackView content is not filled completely inside scrollView as it is aligned to left side. I have attached relevant screens below

**View in storyboard**

[image]

**View in Device**

[image]

**ScrollView IB inspector**

[image]

**Account StackView IB inspector**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting **StackView** constraints to **content layout guide** of scrollView instead of **ScrollView** itself, and setting **equal width** constraint of **StackView** and  solved the problem for me. Screenshots of steps are attached below

1. Attached top, leading and trailing constraints to content layout guide

[image]

2. Set equal width constraints to stack view and parent scrollView

[image]